# Why is my systemd unit not reading env variables properly?

Tags: environment-variables, coreos, systemd, kubernetes, fleet

I am trying to run kubernetes on coreos.  I am using fleet, setup-network-environment, and kube-register to register nodes.  However, in my cloud-init file where I write my systemd unit files, the kubelet's unit file won't run this properly:

```
 ExecStart=/opt/bin/kubelet  \
 --address=0.0.0.0 --port=10250 \
 --hostname_override=${DEFAULT_IPV4} \
 --allow_privileged=true \
 --logtostderr=true \
 --healthz_bind_address=0.0.0.0
```

Instead of my public ip, `${DEFAULT_IPV4}` results in `$default_ipv4`, which also doesn't result in the ip.  I know `--host-name-override` should just take a string, and it works when I run this line from command line.  There are other unit files where `${ENV_VAR}` works fine.  Why is it that for the kubelet's unit file, it just breaks?

**EDIT 1**

/etc/network-environment

```
LO_IPV4=127.0.0.1
ENS33_IPV4=192.168.195.242
DEFAULT_IPV4=192.168.195.242
ENS34_IPV4=172.22.22.238
```

**EDIT 2**

kubelet unit file

```
- name: kube-kubelet.service
  command: start
  content: |
    [Unit]
    Description=Kubernetes Kubelet
    Documentation=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
    Requires=setup-network-environment.service
    After=setup-network-environment.service
    [Service]
    EnvironmentFile=/etc/network-environment
    ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/curl -L -o /opt/bin/kubelet -z /opt/bin/kubelet https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v0.18.2/bin/linux/amd64/kubelet
    ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod +x /opt/bin/kubelet
    # wait for kubernetes master to be up and ready
    ExecStartPre=/opt/bin/wupiao 172.22.22.10 8080
    ExecStart=/opt/bin/kubelet \
    --address=0.0.0.0 \
    --port=10250 \
    --hostname_override=172.22.22.21 \
    --api_servers=172.22.22.10:8080 \
    --allow_privileged=true \
    --logtostderr=true \
    --healthz_bind_address=0.0.0.0 \
    --healthz_port=10248
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem the issue was in the version of coreos in the vagrant box.  After an update of the vagrant box the environment variable was able to resolve to the proper value.

Answer (score 3):

The Exec*=command is not a shell command.  In my experimenting it was not very good at figuring out where the variable was unless it was by itself.  I went and looked at some examples online and they always show the environment variable by itself.  So, given a file like /tmp/myfile:

```
ENV=1.2.3.4
```

These [Service] definitions won't do what you think:

```
EnvironmentFile=/tmp/myfile
ExecStart=echo M$ENV
ExecStart=echo $ENV:8080
```

but, this will work on a line by itself:

```
EnvironmentFile=/tmp/myfile
ExecStart=echo $ENV
```

That doesn't help much when trying to pass an argument, like:

```
EnvironmentFile=/tmp/myfile
ExecStart=echo --myarg=http://$ENV:8080/v2
```

To accomplish passing the argument I had to put the entire myarg in a string in /tmp/myfile:

```
ENV="--myarg=http://1.2.3.4:8080/v2"
```

Finally I could can get my argument passed:

```
EnvironmentFile=/tmp/myfile
ExecStart=echo $ENV
```

Comment: Where is `d` coming from? I'm using the default /etc/network-environment from setup-network-environment, I did mention I am using it.  I'm not running on digital ocean, this is on local VMs and eventually gce.

Comment: Can you post your cloud text?  Also, it would help to know the contents of /etc/network-environment after setup-network-environment runs.  the ${d..} stuff comes from template arguments. My template resolves to --hostname_override=$public_ip, i'll modify the answer to contain the resolved text.

Comment: how about the cloud-init text?  at least the complete unit definition for kubelet.

Comment: well, i'm stumped.  i assume that you have --hostname_override=$DEFAULT_IPV4, and that doesn't work.  The only difference I see between ours is I have a newline between [Unit] and [Service]. I don't think that makes a difference.

Comment: yeah I doubt that's the issue, but I'll give it a try anyway.

Comment: this was bugging me, i had an issue with one of my systemd service files.  i had to do some extra scripting to create temporary environment files suitable for input to systemd.  maybe this approach will work for you.

Comment: the variable that needs the replacement can't touch any other text on either side.  it definitely worked for me. i hope you find a solution.